# Questions (even unanswered ones) from our site are being illegally cloned

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Not sure if this is the right forum but it looks like we got us a content thief boys and girls. See the following:

[Seeking details for the "historical rate" of arable land loss](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/seeking-details-for-the-historical-rate-of-arable-land-loss/6627#6627)

vs

http://letmeask.co/foxfeedspro/details/item_104080/seeking-details-for-the-quot-historical-rate-quot-of-arable-land-loss/

I found this while doing a Google search for the quoted phrase in the question:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Arable+land+loss+is+estimated+to+be+at+30+to+35+times+the+historical+rate.%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: By the way: While this site appears to only be listing "referals" to the questions (they do link back to us) they are also harvesting detailed answers. See the following: http://letmeask.co/foxfeedspro/details/item_778/how-did-the-monkey-king-sun-wukong-go-from-fictional-character-to-religious/

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for pointing this out.  The wholesale copying of stack exchange is fine as long as work is attributed to the authors.  All content contributed to SE is done so under the [CC-BY-SA-3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).  I don't think attribution is met since their post is attributed to "Admin" and the usernames of the content creators are not displayed.  Whether the link back to the question suffices, I cannot say.  Where they definitely fall afoul of SE is in the use of static content such as the icon they use for Earth Science, which is just the favicon for this site.

The policy regarding scraping sites is outlined in [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do).  Basically if a site is

- not attributing content properly, or
- relicensing content with a different license, or
- outranks us in google, or
- is simply a proxy, or
- serves malware

then it should be reported via the [contact us](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the help center.  I'll submit this site for you, so you don't need to make a report unless you really want to.

Comment: +casey: While it is not *good* SE practice to say "thanks" for an answer, allow me to at least thank you for relaying the information to the appropriate people on my behalf. Much appreciated.